# Is there any way to set initial delay (i.e 30 sec) in Vertx and then run task periodically with different time delay (i.e 1 sec)

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks, vert.x

I am using vert.x framework to write a Java application. I have a use case where I need to wait for 30 seconds before scheduling task for 1 second interval.

I am using vertx.setPeriodic to execute task every 1 second. Here I am not able to find any utility of vertex which allows me to wait for 30 seconds initially before executing task every 1 second. I can use Thread.sleep(30000), but it will make my code synchronous. Rather I am looking for a vertx function which allow me to achieve same behavior asyc way.

```
vertx.setPeriodic(1000, timerId -> { ... my task logic ... });
```

I tried using vertx.setPeriodic, but it do not have overloaded method which allows initial delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be simple in combination with `vertx.setTimer(long delay, Handler<Long> handler)`

Your code would look like this:

```
vertx.setTimer(30000, timerId -> {
    vertx.setPeriodic(1000, periodicId -> { ... my task logic ... });
});
```

EDIT: in recent versions of Vert.x, [`setPeriodic`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Vertx.html#setPeriodic-long-long-io.vertx.core.Handler-) initial delay can be configured:

```
vertx.setPeriodic(30000, 1000, timerId -> {
 // My task
});
```

Comment: Thank you Pendula. First solution worked for me!! 

@tsegismont : May I know since which version vertx support delay?

Comment: Version 4.3.4 https://github.com/vert-x3/wiki/wiki/4.3.4-Release-Notes